# Trying to do Dependency Injection with MEF and getting errors

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mef

After setting up my dependency injection I get MEF errors with a cardinality mismatch. I believe I am correctly exporting from the interfaces and when I inspect the program the actual catalog is empty. Not sure what I am doing wrong!

**Container Composition**

```
 private static CompositionContainer CreateContainer()
     {
         AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
         catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(IClient).Assembly));
         CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
         return container;     
     }
```

**Create Container**

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         CompositionContainer container = CreateContainer();
         IClient contactList = container.GetExportedValue<IClient>();

         // More code below, but error is happening on the above line
     }
```

**Client Import**

```
namespace MyWcfProgram.WcfProgram
{
    [Export(typeof(IClient))]
    public class Client : IClient
    {    
        private readonly ILogic contactLogic;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public Client([Import] ILogic contactLogic)
        {
            if(contactLogic == null)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            } else
            {
                this.contactLogic = contactLogic;
            }
        }

        // MORE BELOW LEFT OUT
    }
```

**Logic Import**

```
namespace MyWcfProgram.Logic
{
    [Export(typeof(ILogic))]
    public class Logic : ILogic
    {
        private readonly IData dataAccess;

         [ImportingConstructor]
        public Logic([Import] IData dataAccess)
        {
            if (dataAccess == null)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            this.dataAccess = dataAccess;
        }
```

**Data.cs**

```
namespace MyWcfProgram.Data
{
    [Export(typeof(IData))]
    public class Data : IData
    {
        private string connectionString = "CONNECTION STRING IS HERE";
        private System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myconnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();

        // More code below, but no constructor since there are no dependencies

}
```

Comment: Does `ImportingConstructor` need to have `Import` attribute for constructor parameter?

Comment: Yes, updated to include the logic as well.. the dataAccess does not have any dependencies being imported

Comment: Added data anyway just in case there is an issue with it

Comment: I mean that `ImportingConstructor` need to have parameters with `Import` attribute: `public Client([Import] ILogic contactLogic)`

Comment: Ahh.. I see! So just added the import attribute to the parameters and my catalog is still empty after adding IClient to it.

Comment: Do you have it all in a same assembly?

Comment: Just copied your code in the Console application and everything works fine. Can you provide exact Exception message you got?

Comment: If not in a same assembly: Is `Client` in the same assembly as `IClient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you didn't ask this but might I suggest using SimpleInjector instead if you dont have a hard dependency on MEF. MEF is antiquated and if all you need is an IOC framework you're life will be infinitely better using SimpleInjector instead.

**Container Composition**

```
 private static Container CreateContainer()
     {
         var container = new Container();

         container.Register<IClient, MyWcfProgram.WcfProgram.Client>();
         container.Register<ILogic, MyWcfProgram.Logic.Logic>();
         container.Register<IData, MyWcfProgram.Data.Data>();

         return container;     
     }
```

**Create Container**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         var container = CreateContainer();
         IClient contactList = container.GetExportedValue<IClient>();

         // More code below, but error is happening on the above line
     }
```

**Client Import**

```
namespace MyWcfProgram.WcfProgram
{
    public class Client : IClient
    {    
        private readonly ILogic contactLogic;

        public Client(ILogic contactLogic)
        {
            if(contactLogic == null)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            } else
            {
                this.contactLogic = contactLogic;
            }
        }

        // MORE BELOW LEFT OUT
    }
```

**Logic Import**

```
namespace MyWcfProgram.Logic
{
    public class Logic : ILogic
    {
        private readonly IData dataAccess;

        public Logic(IData dataAccess)
        {
            if (dataAccess == null)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            this.dataAccess = dataAccess;
        }
```

**Data.cs**

```
namespace MyWcfProgram.Data
{
    public class Data : IData
    {
        private string connectionString = "CONNECTION STRING IS HERE";
        private System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myconnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();

        // More code below, but no constructor since there are no dependencies

}
```